# sampling random floats on a range in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

How can I sample random floats on an interval [a, b] in numpy? Not just integers, but any real numbers. For example,

`random_float(5, 10)`

would return random numbers between `[5, 10]`. thanks.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

The [uniform distribution](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.uniform.html) would probably do what you are asking.

```
np.random.uniform(5,10) # A single value
np.random.uniform(5,10,[2,3]) # A 2x3 array
```

Answer (score 8):

EDIT: just use `random.uniform(10, 15)` instead

---

<s>without numpy you can do this with the random module.</s>

```
import random
random.random()*5 + 10
```

will return numbers in the range 10-15, as a function:

```
>>> import random
>>> def random_float(low, high):
...     return random.random()*(high-low) + low
...
>>> random_float(5,10)
9.3199502283292208
>>> random_float(5,10)
7.8762002129171185
>>> random_float(5,10)
8.0522023132650808
```

`random.random()` returns a float from 0 to 1 (upper bound exclusive).  multiplying it by a number gives it a greater range. ex `random.random()*5` returns numbers from 0 to 5.  Adding a number to this provides a lower bound. `random.random()*5 +10` returns numbers from 10 to 15.  I'm not sure why you want this to be done using numpy but perhaps I've misunderstood your intent.

Answer (score 4):

```
import numpy as np
>>> 5 + np.random.sample(10) * 5
array([ 7.14292096,  6.84837089,  6.38203972,  8.80365208,  9.06627847,
        5.69871186,  6.37734538,  9.60618347,  9.34319843,  8.63550653])
```

Answer (score 0):

General syntax:

```py
np.random.uniform(range a, rang b, (rows, columns))
```

For example:
`np.random.uniform(5,10, (3,6))`

Here the values being filled in the array: (5 will be inclusive, and 10 will be exclusive ) in an array of 3 rows and 6 columns.

Answer (score 0):

For a **uniform distribution** of floats on a **closed interval [5,10]**, have a look at python's [random library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.uniform). Beware that this library should not be used for security purposes!

```py
import random
random.uniform(5,10)
```

For a **half open interval [5,10)**, therefore exluding 10.0 itself, you can use the [numpy version](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.Generator.uniform.html#numpy.random.Generator.uniform).

```py
import numpy as np
np.random.default_rng().uniform(5,10)
```